# How can I make the command prompt window open in the top left corner?

Tags: c++, codeblocks

I'm fairly new (about 10 weeks into an level 1 high school course) and I'm trying to see how I can format the command prompt window. I've learned how to set the size of the window, but not the position. I'm using code::blocks on a windows XP

Comment: Fairly hard to miss if you know already figured out how to set the size.  Use SetConsoleWindowInfo().  Focus on writing programs that do interesting and useful things instead of trying to control the machine.  The user already knows how to move the console window and is unlikely to be pleased with your choices.  Write a calculator, good starter project that exercises coding skills.

Comment: If you posted some code of your attempt, it would make it possible to give more relevant help :)

Answer (score 0):

First,  ***[Read This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11008684/change-the-layout-of-cmd-prompt/11010808#11010808)***
Then, try these... (in a batch file)

```
Set mycmdHeight=40
Set mycmdWidth=80
Set mycmdxPos=0
Set mycmdyPos=120
```

Or, programmatically, look ***[here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682073%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)*** or ***[here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682087%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)***

Answer (score 0):

You can use windows function to move the console windows in your desire location.
First look the function to return the handle of current windows.

```
HWND WINAPI GetConsoleWindowNT(void)
{
// declare function pointer type

typedef HWND WINAPI (*GetConsoleWindowT)(void);

// declare one such function pointer

GetConsoleWindowT GetConsoleWindow;

// get a handle on kernel32.dll

HMODULE hK32Lib = GetModuleHandle(TEXT("KERNEL32.DLL"));

// assign procedure address to function pointer

GetConsoleWindow = (GetConsoleWindowT)GetProcAddress(hK32Lib,TEXT("GetConsoleWindow"));

// check if the function pointer is valid

// since the function is undocumented

if ( GetConsoleWindow == NULL ) {
     return NULL;
}

// call the undocumented function

return GetConsoleWindow();
}
```

Use above function to get the handle of current window.

```
HWND hwnd = GetConsoleWindowNT();
```

Now, you can move your windows at your desire location using MoveWindow function like below:

```
MoveWindow(hWnd,1230,750,200,100,TRUE);
```

You can get the complete sample program [here](http://www.codeincodeblock.com/2011/03/move-console-windows-using-codeblock.html).